# Forcing TLS 1.2 in Guzzle

Tags: php, guzzle

I'm using `GuzzleHttp\Client` to communicate with an API. The operator of the API is disabling SSL and pre-1.2 TLS, and has told me my application is still using an earlier protocol.

How can I ensure Guzzle is only using the latest? I'm not sure what my Guzzle version is (I didn't set this up), it's not indicated anywhere in the source code.

Comment: It is possible that your client supports TLS 1.2, and will be fine when that's the only protocol available. You don't need to force Guzzle to use the latest versions of TLS: the server is taking the older versions away anyway. The question you really need to ask is "Does my client *support* TLS 1.2?" You don't need to worry about *forcing* your client to use it: the server will do that.

Answer (score 4):

Up until recently, I worked for a company called WePay that dealt with financial information and was impacted by the PCI-DSS changes which stated that earlier versions of TLS were no longer considered secure, and that we needed all of our customers to get pushed to TLS 1.2. This PCI-DSS requirement ended up being relaxed until June 2018, but you should still make sure you are compatible as early as possible.

I was tasked with doing the research to find out how our customers would be impacted (e.g., PHP, Java, Ruby, C#), and to document everything I found. What I write here is from memory, since I no longer work for WePay or have access to their internal Confluence pages.

---

Guzzle has multiple transport methods, including PHP streams, as well as the cURL extension for PHP.

1. PHP Streams (such as `fsockopen()`) have no guarantees about TLS support, so really, you should make sure your PHP installation has the PHP cURL extension installed (including the underlying `libcurl.so` library, 
   assuming your web servers are Linux).
2. Your underlying curl/libcurl MUST be version 7.35.0 or *newer*. Consumer-oriented Linuxes may have a newer version. I can tell you than CentOS/RHEL/OracleLinux 6.8 ships with cURL 7.19.0 (too old) and 7.3 ships with 7.29.0 (also too old). I don't spend a lot of time with Ubuntu/Debian/SLES, so you'll need to investigate those options on your own. For CentOS/RHEL/OracleLinux, you can either compile and package cURL yourself, or you can depend on the cURL from the [Cityfan](http://www.city-fan.org/ftp/contrib/yum-repo/) repo (which depends on packages from [EPEL](https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/)).

   As always, *never trust third-party dependencies blindly*. Either know who compiles/packages the code and trust them as a resource, or compile/package the code yourself.
3. You will also need a compatible version of PHP. The first versions of PHP which had support for TLS 1.2 were PHP 5.5.19 and PHP 5.6.3. Versions of PHP older than 5.6.0 are EOL and are no longer receiving any security updates, so from one professional to another, I would **strongly** encourage you to upgrade if your version is older than 5.6.0.
4. Some developers who are not PHP natives may use code that *works*, but is actually bad for you. In a large, legacy codebase, it's not uncommon to see:

   1. Old-school *stream functions* (e.g., `fsockopen()`, `fopen($remote_url)`). These are generally considered Bad™ for HTTP(S) requests, and are unreliable as far as TLS support is concerned.
   2. Calling `curl_*` functions directly. cURL is a very complex beast, that has many good options and many bad options. As a general rule, if you're using cURL functions in PHP directly, it is almost certain that you are Doing It Wrong™.
   3. The best approach is to be using a dedicated, well-written, well-tested HTTP library such as Guzzle (or Requests, or Buzz) for 100% of your web service calls. These libraries are Good™.

If you are certain that:

- The underlying server has cURL/libcurl version 7.35.0 or newer installed…
- You have a new enough version of PHP installed (recommended *at least* 5.6.3)…
- And are using Guzzle for 100% of your calls to HTTP(S) endpoints…

Then you are in good shape. Once the service flips the switch to require TLS 1.2, your application will automatically start using TLS 1.2.